# SLR vs CLR parser

Tags: compilers, parsers

In SLR we use follow set of a non terminal for determining reduce moves and in CLR we use lookaheads for the same.

How does using lookaheads actually help in improving the performance of the parser ?

Why is computing lookahead better than computing follow set for parsing ?

Comment: Because it is more precise. You'll find examples of LR grammars which are not SLR in any compilers/formal languages textbook.

Comment: Yes I have seen some examples in books but I am not able to understand the exact reason on how lookaheads help in being more precise.